# Xamarin Forms Frame.IsClippedToBounds not working on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, frame, clipped

I've working on some page in my app and I just find out `Frame.IsClippedToBounds` property is not clipping its content. Here is a piece of code in my XAML:

```
<Frame Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White"
    CornerRadius="50" BorderColor="Teal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
    IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <Frame.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

It works perfectly in iOS but not in Android as you can see in the attachments bellow.

**iOS**

[image: iOS Sample]

**Android**

[image: Android Sample]

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute HeightRequest is giving you the issue; remove this property and IsClippedToBounds will work

Answer (score 0):

This quetion has be reported on GitHub and be fixed. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6358

You could update your Xamarin.forms version to latest.

I test on Xamarin.forms 4.3.0.908675. It works well.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Wendy, thanks for replying. I saw that thread on GitHub too. Unfortunatelly it's not working on my side, I'm using XF 4.4.0.991477. Hope there is a solution soon.

Comment: I test with the same XF version with you. It still works well. Does any other settings you i missed? You could check on a new project.